# javascript - wrap selection in html tag (and unwrap it)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a script that highlights a selection on a web page with an html tag and unhighlights it when another selection is made.  I can almost do it but for some reason it breaks the html when the selection goes to a new line.  It's seems like it's adding p tags.  Here is my code.

```
(function(){
  /**
   * Check and set a global guard variable.
   * If this content script is injected into the same page again,
   * it will do nothing next time.
   */
    if (window.hasRun) {
        return;
    }
    window.hasRun = true;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    let selectedID = 'highlightID';
    let lastSelected;
    function wrap(mouseEvent){
        unwrap();
        let selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        let selectedText = selection.extractContents(); 
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        span.id = selectedID;
        selection.insertNode(span);
        lastSelected = span.innerHTML;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function unwrap(){
        if(lastSelected){
            let highlight = document.getElementById(selectedID);
            highlight.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',lastSelected);
            highlight.parentNode.removeChild(highlight);
            lastSelected = undefined;
        }
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  (function detectSelection(){
    document.onmouseup = wrap;
    document.onkeyup = wrap;
  })();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
})();
```

I'm kind of new to JS so go easy on me.

Comment: Code doesn't add anything to add a line break, most likely there's a style defined for the span element you wrapping your selection into that does it. Inspect your page in Chrome and you'll see it all.

Comment: Yeah more description may be needed here. Im having trouble following what you want to accomplish. `when another selection is made` is based on mouse event clicks i gather.

Comment: I'm intending this to work for firefox and I use ctrl+shift+j to inspect it but it gives me no errors and when I look at the source I can see the p tags added.  @GetSet all I want it to do for now is show a yellow highlight what the user selected which it does but the problem is in removing that highlight.  It's adding line breaks.  I can do it by reloading the page but I want something quicker and simpler if that makes sense.